# Retrieve stored radio button value from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have drop down list in my EditDevice view file which I have loaded values from the database.

```
    <select name="TrackerType" name="Type" id="Type"  style="width:68% !important;">
    <option <?php echo ($devicearray['type']=='mobile'?'selected="selected"':''); ?>>mobile</option>
    <option <?php echo ($devicearray['type']=='third party'?'selected="selected"':''); ?>>third  party</option>
    <option <?php echo ($devicearray['type']=='other'?'selected="selected"':''); ?>>other</option>
```

Now I want to retrieve the selected value in my controller file.

```
      $NewDeviceArray["Type"] = $this->input->post("Type");
```

But  I don't get the selected value when I print the Type.

```
     var_dump($NewDeviceArray["Type"]);
```

So, my question is how to get the selected value from drop down to a variable in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<select name="Type" id="Type"  style="width:68% !important;">


    <option value="mobile" <?php echo ($devicearray['type']=='mobile'?'selected="selected"':''); ?>>mobile</option>
    <option value="third  party" <?php echo ($devicearray['type']=='third party'?'selected="selected"':''); ?>>third  party</option>
    <option value="other" <?php echo ($devicearray['type']=='other'?'selected="selected"':''); ?>">other</option>
    </select>
```